# Creating XML string with multiple items in PHP

Tags: php, xml, string

I'm trying to create an XML string in PHP, with a loop. But I get a parse error.

This is the XML string I'm trying to create:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<DOCUMENT>;

while ($stmt->fetch())
{ 
  $xmlstr.= 
             <ORDER>
               <ORDERNUMBER>$ordernumber</ORDERNUMBER>
               <USERNAME>$username</USERNAME>
               <EMAIL>$mail</EMAIL>
               <STATUS>$status</STATUS>
               </ORDER>;
           };

  $xmlstr.= 
  </DOCUMENT>
  XML;
```

Comment: Why not use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)?

Comment: Its like you're trying to use a heredoc but you never started it, only ended it....and you're trying to continue it throughout a loop...which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build the xml manually, you can either append each line:

```
$xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
$xmlstr .="    <DOCUMENT>";

while ($stmt->fetch())
{ 
    $xmlstr.= "    <ORDER>";
    $xmlstr.= "        <ORDERNUMBER>$ordernumber</ORDERNUMBER>";
    $xmlstr.= "        <USERNAME>$username</USERNAME>";
    $xmlstr.= "        <EMAIL>$mail</EMAIL>";
    $xmlstr.= "        <STATUS>$status</STATUS>";
    $xmlstr.= "    </ORDER>";
};

$xmlstr.= "    </DOCUMENT>";
```

Or use output buffering:

```
//start output buffer
ob_start();
//exit php mode and write xml directly
?>
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <DOCUMENT>
    <?php while ($stmt->fetch()):?>
        <ORDER>
            <ORDERNUMBER><?php echo $ordernumber;?></ORDERNUMBER>
            <USERNAME><?php echo $username;?></USERNAME>
            <EMAIL><?php echo $mail;?></EMAIL>
            <STATUS><?php echo $status;?></STATUS>
        </ORDER>;
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </DOCUMENT>
<?php
//save buffer to variable and flush buffer
$xmlstr = ob_get_clean();
```